# preserve dataframe name using dplyr group_split

Tags: r, dplyr

using group_split from dplyr but I need every dataframe in the list to preserve the name.

Example from dplyr documentation (notice the dataframes are numbered. The optimal output is every dataframe to have the name of the grouped variable (Setosa, versicolor....):

```
    ir <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species)

group_split(ir)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 50 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # … with 40 more rows
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 50 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#>  1          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>  2          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>  4          5.5         2.3          4           1.3 versicolor
#>  5          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#>  6          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
#>  7          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
#>  8          4.9         2.4          3.3         1   versicolor
#>  9          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 10          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
#> # … with 40 more rows
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 50 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>    
#>  1          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica
#>  2          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
#>  3          7.1         3            5.9         2.1 virginica
#>  4          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
#>  5          6.5         3            5.8         2.2 virginica
#>  6          7.6         3            6.6         2.1 virginica
#>  7          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica
#>  8          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
#>  9          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8 virginica
#> 10          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
#> # … with 40 more rows
#> 
#> attr(,"ptype")
#> # A tibble: 0 x 5
#> # … with 5 variables: Sepal.Length <dbl>, Sepal.Width <dbl>,
#> #   Petal.Length <dbl>, Petal.Width <dbl>, Species <fct>
```

Answer (score 6):

`group_split` does not preserve names. From `?group_split`

> it does not name the elements of the list based on the grouping as this typically loses information and is confusing.

You could use base `base::split` for that

```
split(iris, iris$Species)
```

Or name the list of tibbles separately using `setNames`.

```
library(dplyr)
group_split(ir) %>% setNames(unique(iris$Species))
```

`group_split` split based on factor levels of data, so if we want to split them based on their occurrence in the data, we might have to rearrange the factor levels. In `iris` dataset the factor levels are in the same order as they occur in the data, hence the above works.

More generally we should use.

```
iris %>%
  mutate(Species= factor(Species, levels = unique(Species))) %>%
  group_split(Species) %>%
  setNames(unique(iris$Species))
```

Comment: How are you sure the correct name is assigned?

Comment: @useRj The example shared (`iris`) had the same order hence there was no issue. I have updated the answer with a more general solution though. Thanks :)

Comment: One additional item to add if you want to use each of these individual datasets as tibbles: you can save the above code as an object (say, iris_all). Then, you can use this code to get each dataset as a tibble instead of a list: virginica <- iris_all["virginica"]$virginica

Answer (score 0):

We can use `set_names` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
ir %>%
    group_split() %>%
    set_names(levels(iris$Species))
```